# Is it possible to install packages from iso?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, administration

I browsed through the iso file for Ubuntu_14.04_LTS, I found that majority of data were contained in a single file: casper/filesystem.squashfs (922 MB). there is no *.deb files under dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/. The size of the entire directory is just 10K. how can we extract packages from the Ubuntu iso?

Comment: You are asking how applications are installed when you install ubuntu?

Comment: There are tools to decompress the squashfs, though I think they typically mount the file like a hard drive/partition. I'm no expert on this, I've only tinkered. I suspect you can find the binaries in their installed state somewhere in the squashfs; probably in the typical /bin and whats not. Though, copying these binaries to another system man not be particularly easy compared to obtaining original .deb packages elsewhere (or using apt-get in the first place if you have the luxury of an internet connection on the target machine)

Comment: thanks. I now know squashfs is just a zip of installed files. I installed the app using apt-get.